# How to get data without refreshing page between 2 or more user page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hi I am making a progress controll page in our Factory.. I made system with mysql,php..

Everything is done but only one thing I wonder is that:

For now if someone change/add/delete a data from system others have to refresh page to see new datas...

How can everything change without anyone refresh anypage?

Is there a pathway for that or a documantation etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your page on the background (without refresh) periodically using javascript (jQuery's ajax to be more precise)

It basically sends a request to an endpoint (a web address) and then when the results came back, calls your callback function to do whatever you want with the data

You can start here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

## More explanation

This is a working example of background asynchronous request with ajax, which is a simple page that fetches the current exchange rate of Bitcoin (from a public API) every one second, and displays it.

It is really simple to get it up and running, and it also has a lot of more features (like sending custom headers, sending POST or other requests, sending data in the body, etc.)

```js
function fetchData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.coinranking.com/v1/public/coin/1',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#value').html(parseFloat(data.data.coin.price).toFixed(3));
      let d = new Date();
      $('#time').html(`${d.getFullYear()}/${(d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')} ${d.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${d.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`);
    }
  })
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  fetchData();
  window.setInterval(fetchData, 1000)
})
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.value {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
  <p class='title'>Current Bitcoin exchange rate:</p>
  <span class='value'><span id="value">0</span><span>$</span></span>
  <p>(As of <span id='time'></span>)</p>
  <div>
```

Comment: Thanx for kindly reply.. I understand what you mean. but example is a bit insufficient.. can you give me more example.. also againd as a remind :

I want my all web page as "chat" I mean:

When someone update a data.. all other users data will be update without refresh the page...

Comment: You have two options: you can either check the server for any changes periodically (as I suggested in the answer) or you  can use another method that allows the server to notify the clients each time anything changes. The first method is simpler and is suitable for when you don't need too much fast updates (e.g. once a minute or less often). The second method is more complex, is suitable for when you need almost instant updates and you have only a few clients (maybe less than 10 or so). I would recommend you not to go with the second option unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: Let me know which scenario is your use case, so we can discuss the details

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help... I have max 10 user.. I am actually nearly done for our web program... but now everyone need to refresh page all the time to see if there is new update or anything... 

I thought 2 thing:

1) a code that refresh page every for example 10 sec etc but it will distrub users... 
2) a code that call back database every sec to web page html page as "live chat etc"

First is easy to find in internet I think but my chose is two or YOUR FIRST offer...

Can you give me some details about how to do it from server?

Comment: I use those codes in localhost also in w3school also in my web page.. 3 of them ,, doesnt change without refresh page :S

Comment: My bad! There was a bug in the code (the first argument of `setInterval` should be the function handler, without parentheses). Try it now. It also works right here in the stackoverflow snippet viewer

Comment: Yes that is it.. thanks.. :) I will try to put that inside my codes.. Thank you very much you are so kind.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, you can check it as the correct answer, so other people can rely on it

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_folder_list();

 function load_folder_list()
 {
  var action = "fetch";
  $.ajax({
   url:"planlama_action.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{action:action},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#folder_table').html(data);
   }
  });
 }
```

I changed code from up to down... like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_folder_list();

 function load_folder_list()
 {
  var action = "fetch";
  $.ajax({
   url:"planlama_action.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{action:action},
   success:function(data)
   {

    $('#folder_table').html(data);
    setInterval(load_folder_list,1000);
   }
  });
 }
```

And it worked for me.. Thanks to Amir.

But only problem is now.. sometimes that code stop working of web page..

It is irregular... sometimes work perfect.. sometimes become very slow etc...

Why it can be? where is the mistake? (Note: in this page I upload file , change texts etc)